# Change SimpleCursorAdapter to listview in XML

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite Database connection to my application, I have followed a Tutorial and that tutorial show the database in a SimpleCursorAdapter, this does the whole class to this adapter and my buttons can not fit in this class.
I would therefore reduce this adapter to to fit with my buttons.
Or is there any other better solution?
For me the SimpleCursorAdapter Mix all my pictures an button to his adapter,
I dont know but i think that the SCadapter makes the whole view into a list view and i dont want that.
I have four classes.
DBAdapter,
Produkter (View)
Car is the SimpleCursorAdapter ViewBinder
and Bus is the Bitmap get, class

```
enter code here
public class DBhelper {
public static final String KEY_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_KCAL = "kcal";
public static final String KEY_VC = "vitaminc";
public static final String KEY_IMG = "image";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FruitDB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String FRUITS_TABLE = "fruits";
private static final String CREATE_FRUITS_TABLE = "create table "+FRUITS_TABLE+" ("
                                     +KEY_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
                                     +KEY_IMG+" blob not null, "
                                     +KEY_NAME+" text not null unique, "
                                     +KEY_KCAL+" integer not null, "
                                     +KEY_VC+" integer not null);";
                                          private final Context mCtx;
private boolean opened = false;
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_FRUITS_TABLE);
    }
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+FRUITS_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public void Reset() {
    openDB();
    mDbHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1);
    closeDB();
}
public DBhelper(Context ctx) {
    mCtx = ctx;
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
}  
private SQLiteDatabase openDB() {
    if(!opened)
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    opened = true;
    return mDb;
}

public SQLiteDatabase getHandle() { return openDB(); } 
private void closeDB() {
    if(opened)
        mDbHelper.close();
    opened = false;
}

public void createFruitEntry(Bus fruit) {
    openDB();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    fruit.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_IMG, out.toByteArray());            
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, fruit.getName());
    cv.put(KEY_KCAL, fruit.getKcal());
    cv.put(KEY_VC, fruit.getVitaminC());
    mDb.insert(FRUITS_TABLE, null, cv);
    closeDB();
}
}    enter code here
public class produkter extends ListActivity {
    private DBhelper mDB;          
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);              
        mDB = new DBhelper(this);          
        mDB.Reset();           
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),      

 R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                mDB.createFruitEntry(new Bus(img, "Banane",   92, 10));
        mDB.createFruitEntry(new Bus(img, "Kiwi",     56, 71));
        mDB.createFruitEntry(new Bus(img, "Pfirsich", 41, 10));
        mDB.createFruitEntry(new Bus(img, "Zitrone",  40, 51));        
        String[] columns = {mDB.KEY_ID, mDB.KEY_IMG, mDB.KEY_NAME, mDB.KEY_KCAL,   

 mDB.KEY_VC};
        String   table   = mDB.FRUITS_TABLE;           
        Cursor c = mDB.getHandle().query(table, columns, null, null, null, null,   

   null);    
        startManagingCursor(c);
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.produkterx,
                c,
                new String[] {mDB.KEY_IMG, mDB.KEY_NAME, mDB.KEY_KCAL, mDB.KEY_VC},
                new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.txt, R.id.rating});

        adapter.setViewBinder(new Car());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
enter code here
  public class Car implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

            if(view instanceof ImageView) {
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
                    byte[] img = cursor.getBlob(columnIndex);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0,      
 img.length));
                    return true;
            }

            if(view instanceof RatingBar) {
                    RatingBar rb = (RatingBar) view;
                    int kcal = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_KCAL));
                    int vitc = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.KEY_VC));
                    rb.setRating((float) (kcal * ((float) vitc/1000.0)));
                    return true;
            }
           return false;
    }
 }

enter code here
     public class Bus {
private Bitmap bmp;
private String name;
private int kcal;
private int vitaminc;

public Bus(Bitmap b, String n, int k, int v) {
    bmp = b;
    name = n;
    kcal = k;
    vitaminc = v;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() { return bmp; }
public String getName() { return name; }
public int getKcal() { return kcal; }
public int getVitaminC() { return vitaminc; }
}

 enter code here` XML
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/Blue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnE"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="E" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/header2"
        android:src="@drawable/header2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnkontakt"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="k" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnprodukter"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnE"
        android:text="p" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSok"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnprodukter"
        android:text="s" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/sok"
        android:src="@drawable/produkter" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="1" >     

    <ImageView
   android:id = "@+id/img"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
   >
</ImageView>

<TextView
   android:id = "@+id/txt"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerVertical = "true"
   >
</TextView>

<RatingBar
   style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"    
   android:id = "@+id/rating"
   android:numStars = "5"
   android:stepSize = "0.5"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
   android:layout_centerVertical = "true"
   android:layout_marginRight = "5px">
</RatingBar>

 </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout> 



 > Blockquote

       This XML is all in a simpelCA that i dont want!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to the question. Your simple Cursor Adapter is meant to send the data to a listview for populating your screen.

```
startManagingCursor(c);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.produkterx,
        c,
        new String[] {mDB.KEY_IMG, mDB.KEY_NAME, mDB.KEY_KCAL, mDB.KEY_VC},
        new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.txt, R.id.rating});
```

You will want a match for the String[]/int[]. If you don't want to show something don't include it in here.